# Tomcat can't start the app because it can't find JSONRPC2ParseException class

Tags: java, tomcat, json-rpc

I have application in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/code` I have init.java file that use [json-rpc-2.0](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html)

I compile it using:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/jsonrpc2-base-1.35.jar:/path/json-smart-1.2.jar
javac init.java
```

it compile but when I run the app (not the servlet) I got error 404 from Tomcat and in catalina.out file there is exception:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngin
e[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/code]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
a:1114)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig
.java:1673)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thetransactioncompany/jsonrpc2/JSONRPC2ParseException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2387)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1796)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2ParseException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        ... 25 more
```

with caused by not found `com/thetransactioncompany/jsonrpc2/JSONRPC2ParseException` which is in jar file.

What's happening here? How can I fix it to make it work?

Comment: put json-rpc-2.0 jar file in your Tomcat lib folder

Comment: Thanks @Makky, I put into `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` and restart tomcat and it work. You can put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually the jar files are not available for Tomcat.

The best way to solve this is place the `json-rpc-2.0 jar` files into your Tomcat's lib folder

**Update**

As specified by A4L user , you can also put the jar in your web applications `WEB-INF/lib` as well.

Comment: Yes, putting in your server's lib is better if you have more than one application using the same jar.
For example ,servelet-api jar , its not recommended to put in your WEB-INF lib because its already in Tomcat's path. Again, its upto the individual